# React-native: display foreground notifications like background notifications with zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification

I have set up push notifications on my React-native app with [zo0r / react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/) . It works on Android, and on iOS when the app is in background mode.

However, **the notification does not display when the app is in foreground mode with iOS**. I'm aware that I have to handle the notification when in foreground mode but I'd like to display them exactly the same way there are displayed when in background mode.

So I did the following:

```
import {PushNotificationIOS} from 'react-native';

PushNotification.configure({
...
   onNotification: function(notification) {
      if (notification.foreground) {
         PushNotification.localNotification(notification);
      }
      notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
   },
...
}
```

But nothing happens, the notification is still not displayed, what am I missing?

Comment: could you please provide sample implementation for this I am facing issue in `foreground` if I use `PushNotification.localNotification` it shows two (default and Locale)

Comment: You got the problem on iOS, Android or both of them?

Comment: I got problem on android, channel (miscellaneous) is getting created in background notification only not on foreground. I need to keep in background to receive it for very first time cause channel getting created in background.

Comment: I edited my post to show code that does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add some configuration inside the ios file `AppDelegate.m`

Following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lutzk/2e2319d112440348619f4b9b25ae6342) did make it work.

My code look like:

```
onNotification(notification) {
  if (isIos) {
    if (
      notification.foreground &&
      (notification.userInteraction || notification.remote)
    ) {
      PushNotification.localNotification(notification);
    }
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  } else {
    if (notification.foreground) {
      PushNotification.localNotification(notification);
    }
  }
},
```

I also set `popInitialNotification` to  `true`

Answer (score 1):

i think you have missing the configuration in AppDelegate.mm

try to check this snippet.

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
```

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
..............
  [FIRApp configure];
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
...........
  return YES;
}
```

```
////Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```